# In batch programing can one command run before the previous command finishes executing?

Tags: windows, batch-file

In batch programing is one command waited until completed until the next one is run? What I mean is for example

```
net stop wuauserv
net start wuauserv
```

Since `net stop wuauserv` takes a while to complete is it given time to complete or do I need another command to wait until it completes?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: @AbqBill it would be hard to know if it worked or not if I try it...It looks like it works. I was hoping to confirm with someone more experienced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NET STOP` command does wait (or timeout while waiting) for a service to stop or start.
You can check the `%ERRORCODE%` from the command to get more information about if there was a problem or if it worked as expected.

In general most system command line tools return control once they are done executing. A few specialized programs will call into other services or systems and may return control before execution is complete. You will need to check the docs for whatever you are trying to run, but generally processes exit once the 'task' they perform is complete.

Answer (score 0):

In a batch file, all commands are run sequentially, and execution waits for the command to complete.

In your example, `net stop wuauserv` would complete before `net start wuauserv` gets run.

You could confirm that by running something you know will take a long time, such as

```
ping www.google.com
ping www.stackoverflow.com
```

and you'll see that the second ping does not start until the first completes.

Comment: All commands/programs are ran sequentially. However, not all wait for the previous command to finish. Try putting a call to `NOTEPAD` between your `PING` calls and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, yes the second command will not execute until the first finishes.

However, GUI apps will start up and return control the batch file.

For example,

```
PING localhost
NOTEPAD
DIR
```

The `DIR` command will execute even if `NOTEPAD` is still running.